# JSON parsing issues from PHP service

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, json

I'm using json_encode on a two dimensional array in a PHP script like so:

```
$myjsons[] = json_encode(array($runners));
```

And also MANY single dimensional arrays later in the script:

```
$myjsons[] = json_encode(array($mrow));
```

I then echo after encoding the entire array at the end of the script:

```
echo json_encode($myjsons);
```

I'm working on an iOS app that communications with this service. Well, at least it is suppose to. Here is the iOS code minus error checking: (I'm using JSONKit, btw)

```
NSMutableURLRequest *urlReq = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kStartRaceURL]];
[urlReq setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;

NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:urlReq returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];

NSArray *deserializedData = [response objectFromJSONData];
```

The deserializedData is an array, but all objects within it are strings. I put arrays in it though, as shown in the PHP, so why are they NSString's? Where is the problem with the implementation? Or should I do something with the NSString's?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`json_encode` returns a string, so when you put those in an array, you get an array of strings. When you `json_encode` that array, you get a (JSON) string array of strings.

To fix this, you should first merge all your arrays into one large array, and then only call `json_encode` once on that final array. Example:

```
$myjsons[] = array($runners);
$myjsons[] = array($mrow);

echo json_encode($myjsons); // Correct JSON as you expect it.
```

Comment: Honestly, I was thinking that was the problem, though PHP is by no means my language of choice. Thank you!